# Style a Polygon (speed restriction area) with just an SVG Road Sign at either end of the polygon in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, polygon, svg, geometry-generator, ppygis

I have a series of "**zones**" which are **polygons** along a road which have a **speed** attribute, I'd like to rather than just shade the polygons based on speed, actually show the 20mph or 30mph sign at either end of each polygon.

Is there a way to do this in geometry generator, or any other way at all? I'd prefer to keep the layers as polygons as there is a lot of complicated set up in PostGIS in the background.

[image: speed restriction areas]

Here is what I get following @JGH code

collect_geometries(
start_point($geometry),
line_interpolate_point(
boundary( $geometry),
length(boundary( $geometry))/2))

[image]

Comment: It might be simpler to show the speed limit as the polygon centroid, as two adjacent polygons won't have their symbol colliding into each others

Answer (score 1):

You can use the geometry generator to extract the 1st point of the polygon and apply the symbol of your choice

[image]

To get the symbol on both "ends", add a point at 50% of the polygon perimeter:

```
collect_geometries(
 start_point($geometry),
 line_interpolate_point(
    boundary( $geometry), 
    length(boundary( $geometry))/2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have used the code above but it doesnt give me a symbol at each end. Im not sure how to add a picture to show you, so have put it in the original question if you dont mind taking a look.